# How to import into an existing db w/o disturbing existing data

Tags: mysql

I have an existing db and want to use Myadmin to import the following lines into the existing db. this was exported from a different db with exact same fields. so my first attempt was to remove the `listingsdb_id` and keep the comma to get it to use the next id but that failed. So I was able to go into MySQL and find the last used id and then sequentially replace the old id with the new sequential ones that I entered. and that worked fine. however i have thousands of these to do so need to make it easier.

I can program it to insert all the new ids but there must be an easier way. how do it get it to use the next id when I insert using phpMyAdmin into an existing db. At the end and auto to use the next id.

As I said removing the old id and leaving a comma did not work. The second group of code shows my attempt to remove the existing id and leave the comma only hoping it would auto fill the id for me. Using the next one available.

Is there another way since i have 15,000 lines to insert at the end of the db. Of course i can't use the existing 5 digit id as its the old one from the orig export. Need the new one to insert at bottom of new db.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`listingsdb_id`, `user_id`, `class_id`, `Address`)
    VALUES (15566, 1, 1, '9901  TRAILWOOD Drive 2150 Las Vegas Nevada 89134 1604091'),
           (15567, 1, 1, '9901  TRAILWOOD Drive 2053 Las Vegas Nevada 89134 1614493'),
           (15568, 1, 1, '9901  TRAILWOOD Drive 1133 Las Vegas Nevada 89134 1617668')

INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`listingsdb_id`, `user_id`, `class_id`, `Address`)
    VALUES (, 1, 1, '9901  TRAILWOOD Drive 2150 Las Vegas Nevada 89134 1604091'),
           (, 1, 1, '9901  TRAILWOOD Drive 2053 Las Vegas Nevada 89134 1614493'),
           (, 1, 1, '9901  TRAILWOOD Drive 1133 Las Vegas Nevada 89134 1617668')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `listingsdb_id` is auto increment (and it should be), you can just do:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`user_id`, `class_id`, `Address`)
    VALUES (1, 1, '9901  TRAILWOOD Drive 2150 Las Vegas Nevada 89134 1604091'),
           (1, 1, '9901  TRAILWOOD Drive 2053 Las Vegas Nevada 89134 1614493'),
           (1, 1, '9901  TRAILWOOD Drive 1133 Las Vegas Nevada 89134 1617668');
```

If the data is in another table:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`user_id`, `class_id`, `Address`)
    SELECT `user_id`, `class_id`, `Address`
    FROM othertable
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfect.. the data is coming from another export frm another db but i like the idea of maybe importing it into a table on the same db then use option 2... you gave since to use it as option 1 i have to write a tiny program to remove the listingsdb_id and also remove the old listingsid_db and comma.. but if i add a table to my main  db i drop the temp table each time then import as is to the temp table then use option 2... does all that makes sense as I will b doing this weekly with about 5,000 line entrires.
Not sure how this works is there a place to mark as accep ans?